# new year timer cannot set property

Tags: javascript

I have a question why after start this timer in for example google chrome there is an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
at countdown (app.js:15)"
Additionaly if i strat this app in some compilator its work fine but when i start it by browser there is this error. Maybe its stupid question but its my first steps with JavaScript
I am gratefull for help and waste time :)

```js
const daysEl = document.getElementById('days');
const hoursEl = document.getElementById('hours');
const minsEl = document.getElementById('mins');
const secondsEl = document.getElementById('seconds');
const newYears = "1 Jan 2021";
var timer;
function countdown() {
   const newYearsDate = new Date(newYears);
   const currentDate = new Date();
   const totalseconds = (newYearsDate - currentDate) / 1000;
   const days = Math.floor(totalseconds / 3600/24) ;
   const hours = Math.floor(totalseconds / 3600) % 24;
   const mins = Math.floor(totalseconds / 60) % 60;
   const seconds = Math.floor(totalseconds) % 60;
   daysEl.innerHTML = days;
   hoursEl.innerHTML= hours;
   minsEl.innerHTML = mins;
   secondsEl.innerHTML =seconds;
   if(days<=0 && hours<=0 && mins<=0 && seconds<=0){
      window.clearInterval(timer);
   }
}
timer=setInterval(countdown, 1000);
```

```css
*{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;

}

body{
    background-image: url(pexels-adriaan-greyling-764310.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 1100px;


    
}
body > section{
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}
body > section > div{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: black;
  padding-top: 2%;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="app.js"> </script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;800&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>newDate</title>
</head>
<body>

    <section class="dateContainer">
        <h1 class="mainText">New Year Soon...</h1>
        <div class="main">
            
           <div class="day" >
                <p id="days">00</p>
                <span>Days</span>
           </div>
           <div class="hour">
            <p id="hours">00</p>
            <span>Hours</span>
        </div>
        <div class="min">
            <p id="mins">00</p>
            <span>Mins</span> 
        </div>
        <div class="second">
            <p id="seconds">00</p>
            <span>Sec</span>  
        </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to put the script tag before the closing body tag instead of in head.

Comment: Or wrap it with [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event)

Comment: So stupid mistake u where right @yochanansheinberger thak you